# Hide a bunch of Divs after user inactivity

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, onmousemove, idle-timer

I'm using Paul Irish's idle-timer plugin available here : http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/ .

I want to hide some divs after 5 seconds of inactivity and show them back when user activity's catched .

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.idleTimer(5000);
    $(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function(){
        $("#audio_container").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".breadcrumb").fadeOut(1000);
    });
    $(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function(){
        $("#audio_container").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".breadcrumb").fadeIn(1000);
    });
 });
```

It works perfectly on Firefox / Safari / Mobile Safari , but I can't make it work on Chrome or IE 8 / 9 .
Obviously the onmousemove event is the problem, if I unbind the onmousemove event, it works (But I need it so this is not an acceptable fix for me).

You can find an exemple here :

Best regards,

EDIT :

The mousemouve event is located in the idle-timer plugin .

```
$.idleTimer = function(newTimeout, elem){

    // defaults that are to be stored as instance props on the elem

    var idle    = false,        //indicates if the user is idle
        enabled = true,        //indicates if the idle timer is enabled
        timeout = 30000,        //the amount of time (ms) before the user is considered idle
        events  = 'mousemove keydown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel mousedown touchstart touchmove'; // activity is one of these events
```

if I remove the mousemove event from the plugin, it works .

Comment: "Obviously the onmousemove event is the problem" - but you didn't include that part of the code

Comment: Sorry about that actually I'm loading the idle-timer plugin. In the plugin, there's the following code : `code`events  = 'mousemove keydown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel mousedown touchstart touchmove';`code`

Comment: @citizen con : Thank you for your help, I've edited the main post

Comment: Sorry, I must be confused, but it's working for me in Chrome. IE8 actually crashed every time.

Comment: One more thing, on Chrome and IE, the divs fade out if the mouse pointer is not on top of the window .

Comment: Must be my chrome install . I'll have to check on that. So you didn't see the divs disappear on IE8 right ?

Comment: Like I said, IE8 crashed every time, even before the page loaded... but I am using IE9 in IE8 mode for what it's worth.

Comment: Must be the text shadow fix I was using making your browser crash . If you try again it should work ok . Thanks again for your help .

Comment: Could you give it a last try, if it's still crashing, it must be IE8 Mode acting up .

Comment: that worked in IE8 and the players controls hide and show as expected!

Comment: God I love to here that. Looks like my testing environment is not good and I was chasing the wrong bugs :( . Thanks so much for your help .

Comment: Can you make a [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/eKgGG/

Comment: Ok seems to be Working on IE 9 with IE8 Mode on, but not on IE8 itself (tested on XP / 7) : http://eh.akbsystems.jp/sgi-dev/stories/nelson-mandela/

Comment: @Florian Didron - the fiddle works in IE8 for me.  the live link does not

Comment: @Florian Didron - notice that the live link has a ton of stuff happening outside DOMReady - specifically IE8 stuff.  might try placing that code in the ready handler

Answer (score 4):

if u dont have to use the plugin and hide divs or wathever element after five seconds of inactivity and show it once its active again, i came up with a script like so (tested in chrome,firefox, explorer):

http://jsfiddle.net/e8KXw/1/

(Using an input for demonstration instead of div)

```
<input type="text" > /* Use div or any element */
```

Jquery:

```
var interval = 1;

setInterval(function(){
   if(interval == 5){
       /* if intervall reaches 5 the user is inactive hide element/s */
       $('input').hide(); 
       interval = 1;
   }
   interval = interval+1;
    console.log(interval);
},1000);

$(document).bind('mousemove keypress', function() {
    /* on mousemove or keypressed show the hidden input (user active) */
    $('input').show();
    interval = 1;
});
```

Hope its not far from what you are after.
Cheers!

Comment: I added touchmove for mobile too.

$(document).bind('mousemove keypress touchmove', function() {